# Differential Equations: Say whether the equation has bounded solutions at $x = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Its been forever since I've done Diff EQ and I can't remember how to go about solving this problem:

Say whether the equation has bounded solutions at $x = 0$ and whether all solutions are bounded:
$$
(x^2 + x^3)u'' + (x + x^2)u' + u = 0
$$

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.